# How to calculate number of nodes opened by BFS?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, search-algorithms, search-trees

In the below diagram, each node takes up a space of 2KB. I need to find the total memory consumed to reach the goal : I

I know that the equation for BFS is

b<sup>1</sup> + b<sup>2</sup> + ...... + (b<sup>d+1</sup> - b)

Where b is the branching factor and d the depth

But how do I calculate the branching factor in the below diagram, where the branches are **uneven**?

Also, is the depth on A node 0 or 1?

[image: State Space]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of the above diagram, as you mention, there is no constant branching factor. This means that we cannot solve for the number of nodes explored using the formula you give above.

Instead, we must use knowledge of how BFS works in order to calculate which nodes were visited before **Node I** was found. In BFS, nodes adjacent to the current node are marked, and then placed in a queue. The next element in the queue is visited (and removed from the queue), and this process repeats. Use this process to figure out which nodes are visited before **Node I**, and then charge a cost of 2kB for visiting each node.